# Returning a RandomAccessCollection of a specific type

Tags: swift

I have a protocol where I want to express that a function/variable can return a `RandomAccessCollection` of a specific type - not necessarily an `Array` because for one implementation it uses a library to access the data. It's easy to wrap the library calls in a `RandomAccessCollection`-conforming class, so I'd rather not have to construct an `Array` which would involve a bunch of extra copying.

I'm trying something like this:

```
protocol MyThing
{
  var entries: RandomAccessCollection where Element: MyEntry { get }
}
```

..but the compiler doesn't like that; it doesn't seem to like having a `where` clause there.

Is there a way to do this, such that one implementation of my protocol can return a custom `RandomAccessCollection`-conforming class, and another (say, a mock version for testing) can return an `Array`? Or will I need to define a `RandomAccessCollection` for all cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Swift 4

Swift 4 implements the following evolution proposal:

- [SE-0142: Permit where clauses to constrain associated types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0142-associated-types-constraints.md)

which will allow you to add an `associatedtype` to your protocol that can make use of more sophisticated type constraints via a `where` clause; adding constraints not only to the `associatedtype` type itself. E.g., as applied to your example:

```
// Swift 4 and beyond
protocol MyEntry { /* ... */ }

protocol MyThing {
    associatedtype MyCollectionType: RandomAccessCollection
        where MyCollectionType.Iterator.Element: MyEntry
    var entries: MyCollectionType { get }
}

extension Int : MyEntry { /* ... */ }

// OK, Int conforms to MyEntry
struct Foo: MyThing {
    internal var entries: [Int]
}

// Compile time error: Double doesn't conform to MyEntry
struct Bar: MyThing {
    internal var entries: [Double]
}

// OK given that MyCustomRandomAccessCollection conforms
// to RandomAccessCollection
struct Baz: MyThing {
    internal var entries: MyCustomRandomAccessCollection<Int>
}
```

Comment: In an Xcode 9 beta sandbox, that seems to work. I'll just make do with an uglier solution until I can use Swift 4. Thanks.

Comment: @Uncommon Hopefully it's just a couple of months now and we'll be there (which will allow other goodies in addition to the one above).

Comment: Swift 4 is released and SE-0142 implemented.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the prompt! I'm so Swift-inactive I've even missed its release ;(